# Firebase - Unable to serve local function after upgrading to 6.9.0

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

After upgrading `firebase-tools` from `6.8.0` to `6.9.0` my local function stopped working. I get below error message when calling it from my application:

```
λ firebase.cmd serve --only functions:upload
+  functions: Using node@12 from host.
+  functions: Emulator running at http://localhost:5001
i  functions: Beginning execution of "upload"
!  Error: Cannot find module 'package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\MyLocalUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at verifyDeveloperNodeModules (C:\Users\MyLocalUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:125:32)
    at C:\Users\MyLocalUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:457:26
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\MyLocalUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\MyLocalUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:3:12)
!  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

I have reinstalled node and npm entierly (including deleting %appdata% files), deleted all `node_module` files and reinstalled everything with `npm ci` but problem remains.

`firebase.cmd` is version `6.0.0`

How do I continue? I could serve the very same function before upgrading, but now even if trying to downgrade using `npm i firebase-tools@6.8.0` problem remains.

The function right now:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.upload = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log('Upload initiated')
  return null;
});
```

Comment: This will not solve the problem but http functions must return res.status(200) or 500 on error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading from firebase-tools 6.7.2 to 6.9.0

These steps worked for me to roll back to a previous version on Windows 10:

1. Uninstall the functions-emulator
2. Uninstall firebase-tools
3. Remove the functions-emulator config **<== This is the step I didn't know about**
4. Re-install a previous version of firebase-tools (6.7.2 or 6.8.0)

Detailed steps:

Switch nodejs version if you have multiple. I removed the functions-emulator and firebase-tools from all versions. Uninstalling needs to be done for each version separately.

> nvm use 8.16.0

Uninstall the functions-emulator. More info: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator/wiki/Troubleshooting

> npm uninstall -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator

Uninstall firebase-tools

> npm uninstall -g firebase-tools

Delete the functions-emulator configuration folder found at 'C:\Users\yourusername\.config\configstore@google-cloud\functions-emulator'

Install a previous version of firebase-tools. Versions are listed at https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools

> npm install -g firebase-tools@6.8.0

I believe you may only be able to use the functions-emulator with one nodejs version so if you install it with 8.16.0 then make sure you've switched to that version with '> nvm use 8.16.0' before you start testing cloud functions locally

Login to firebase

> firebase login

In your project directory update the functions and admin packages

> npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save

Start testing locally

> firebase functions:shell
>   Or use
>   firebase serve

Note: Calling the functions-emulator directly with 'firebase emulators:start' won't work.

**Follow this issue on github for updates: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1258**